# megatools does not work under Python subprocess

Tags: python, subprocess

megatools (https://megatools.megous.com/) for some reason does not work under Python subprocess. I'm using the latest 1.11.0 version of megatools.

```py
>>> import subprocess as sp
>>> cmd = ['megatools', 'df', '--free', '-u', 'name@mail.com', '-p', 'password']
>>> proc = sp.run(cmd, stdout=sp.PIPE, stderr=sp.PIPE, text=True)
>>> proc.returncode
1
>>> proc.stdout.strip()
'' 
>>> proc.stderr.strip()
"ERROR: Can't login to mega.nz: API call 'us' failed: Server returned error ENOENT"
```

But if you set 'shell' to True, it does work:

```py
>>> proc = sp.run(cmd, stdout=sp.PIPE, stderr=sp.PIPE, text=True, shell=True)
>>> proc.returncode
0
>>> proc.stdout.strip()
'53686321152'
>>> proc.stderr.strip()
''
```

Anyone have any ideas why this is happening?